# Can I append 2 git commits after i push

Tags: git

Is it possible for me to 'git commit --amend' 2 commits AFTER I have pushed?

```
git commit 
git push
git commit
git push
```

Can I some how combine the 2 commits that I did?

Thank you.

Comment: To be clear, you are actually looking to combine those two commits into a single commit, and replace the two you pushed with that one, right? That's not exactly what "append" implies to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this depends on whether it's OK for you to "force push" to your repository - in other words to push a commit that doesn't contain the remote branch as part of its history.  For example, it's certainly OK for you to force push if one of the following applies:

- If it's just you using the repository
- If you know no one will have pulled your changes
- If you can tell your collaborators that you've pushed a rewritten master branch (and they'll know what to do about that!)

If so, then you could go ahead and do the following:

```
# Reset the master branch pointer to the commit before, but leave the index
# and your working tree as is:
git reset --soft HEAD^

# Amend the commit you're now at with the current index:
git commit --amend

# Push the master branch with '-f' for '--force':
git push -f master
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean "amend", not "append". In any case, while it's certainly possible to do anything you want, it's a rather bad idea to go modifying history (which amend does) once you've pushed.